# excel VBA listobject autofilter error simple filter criteria error

Tags: excel, filtering, listobject, vba

Why is this filter not working as expected:

```
Dim clsSht As Worksheet
    Set clsSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("claims")
    clsSht.Activate
Dim myTable As ListObject
    Set myTable = clsSht.ListObjects(1)
myTable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1"
```

The sheet "claims" contains a table named table3 that I access via `clsSht.ListObjects(1)` since it is the only listobject in that sheet.

This nomenclature for filtering the table is extensibly used in other posts of StackOverflow and other websites.

The error is:

> run-time erroe 1004 Autofilter method of range class failed.

Substituting the last line by:

```
myTable.DataBodyRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1"
```

does not work neither. Same error.

I also activated sheet("claims") before running the code. Same error.

I changed again the filter line by:

```
myTable.DataBodyRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1", Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Same error.

The table looks like this:

[image]

Being the first column the first field of the table.

I looked at tens of pages on the internet and surprisingly I found this syntax very often as solution for filtering tables.

Where is the catch?

Comment: Is the sheet protected?

Comment: What happens if you change `Set myTable = clsSht.ListObjects(1)` to `Set myTable = clsSht.ListObjects("Table3")`?  Is it possible that there is a deprecated/unused ListObject in the sheet? (Try running `?clsSht.ListObjects.Count` in the immediate window, or `?clsSht.ListObjects(1).Range.Address(True, True, xlA1)` to check the Range)

Comment: No protected. Comented out the filter and added:
    If clsSht.ProtectContents = True Then
        MsgBox "somethign is protected"
    End If
result: no protection.

Comment: @Chronocidal There is only one listobject in the sheet and address of listobject 1 is A3:k12 as expected

Comment: I checked it out with:
    `MsgBox "number of tables:" & clsSht.ListObjects.Count`
    and 
    `MsgBox clsSht.ListObjects(1).Range.Address(True, True, xlA1)`